# Modal's properties like NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, literals

I once read an article about accessing properties fast, but forget how to do it.

Let's say I have two arrays. One filled with dictionaries and one filled with objects of type `YBUser`. The dictionaries have a key 'name' and `YBUser` has a property 'name'.

Getting the name key from the dictionary is easy: `dictionaries[0][@"name"]`. But how would I do this with the model? Best I could come up with is `((YBUser *)objects[0]).name`. This doesn't look so good.

Could somebody help me out and tell me how to access a model's property like a dictionary?

P.S.

Of course I could use the code below, but I'd like to do it shorter / like a dictionary?

```
YBUser *user = objects[0];
NSLog(@"user.name: %@", user.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use KVC to do what you want and it would look like follows

```
[objects[0] valueForKeyPath:@"name"]
```

I really think that you should use the way you dont want to use since it ensure that you have an object of the correct type (as long as objects contains all the same type) and that the property actually exists. If you really want to have dictionary-like access use a dictionary. The point of a model is to have defined objects that represent actual things that you want rather than abstract key-value pairs. Just my opinion anyways.